# View the body of an assembly file(.NET 5)

Tags: c#, .net-5

I was messing around with sockets and streams in visual studio so to get the best understanding I thought *"Is there a way to view method's body?"*.

When I go to definition (F12) of a Type (like `Socket`) I only get it's Metadata, is there a way to view the methods and their body with some comments to get a better understanding on how things work inside?

Comment: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/, https://github.com/dotnet/.

Comment: Usually I just google "github [namespace/class]" and find the official ms repo. E.g. [Socket](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Net.Sockets/src/System/Net/Sockets/Socket.cs). You don't want to include everything, as that would be A LOT. And things would get really slow...